# Transform Data Option In PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

Being a beginner in PowerBI, I am trying to import dataset on online portal of PowerBI(aap.powerbi.com). When I upload the data, I am not able to see the option to transform or manipulate data. What is the way I can access this without using power BI desktop

Answer (score 0):

The PowerQuery or the Trasnform Data option is only available in PowerBI cloud. Even if you want to create measures or new columns you'll have to do it on the desktop, there's no way around this unfortunately currently. If it is possible in the future, let me know here!

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use power bi desktop to data manipulation and preparation part.